# Oracle: "super-select" over few results amazingly slow

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I needed to execute a select in Oracle 11G which looked like this:

```
select distinct p_date, column1, column2, ...
from table1 t1, table2 t2, ...
where (some join relations)
  and t1.p_date > to_date('010113','ddmmrr')
```

At some point, I realized that the filer over the p_date made the query very slow, while the same query without the p_date filter was almost immediate.
On top of that, I realized that the query without filter returned a small set of results, about 30 rows, so I thought about moving the date filter outside the query.

I tried these two options:

```
with temp as (
select distinct p_date, column1, column2, ...
from table1 t1, table2 t2, ...
where (some join relations)
) select * from temp where p_date > to_date('010113','ddmmrr')
```

and

```
select * from (
select distinct p_date, column1, column2, ...
from table1 t1, table2 t2, ...
where (some join relations)
) where p_date > to_date('010113','ddmmrr')
```

expecting it to be almost as fast as the inner query, since it should execute it first, and then apply the p_date filter only to the 30 rows returned.

Howerever, in both cases the execution time was enourmous (I cannot tell how much because I was not patient enough to wait for the results to come up).

Can someone tell me the why this happens?

As a side note: the table "table1" has an index over p_date which looks like not working as expected (I'm also taking care of that). But, may Oracle engine identify that and wrongly reengineer the query at runtime to try using it?

Thanks in advance,

Carles

Comment: Please post the execution plans.

Comment: Please also post the exact join between the tables, the Oracle version number, and the table definitions

Comment: The Oracle optimiser can rewrite the query if it thinks it's going to be faster to push the data predicate into the sub-select, yes. You'd need to trace it to see exactly what it's doing, but the execution plans should show you that it's still using the `p_date` index (probably, from what you've described). There are hints that can avoid that, but you need to understand why it's happening before trying those.

Comment: it was never "almost immediate", good chance when you ran without the filter it was pulling most blocks from buffer cache (from the previous run of the query).

Answer (score 0):

1. "some join relations"? Some description...
2. You are using distinct keyword which is utilizing TEMP pretty heavily.
3. If there is an index over p_date then try to use hint: /*+ INDEX */

   select /*+ INDEX (table_name index_name)*/ distinct p_date, column1, column2, ...

   from table1 t1, table2 t2, ...

   where (some join relations)

   and t1.p_date > to_date('010113','ddmmrr')